# Facebook OpenGraph Stories in Android Facebook SDK 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sdk-4.0

Following this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android), I'm trying to implement OpenGraph stories in Android application, with Facebook SDK 4.0.
I have read a lot of Facebook documentation, and understand (in theory) how OpenGraph stories should work. But the main problem, that I can't implement it in SDK 4.0, because all code samples in tutorials and documentation are referred to the old SDK's methods. And all my attempts to make it work (change Actions, Objects) have failed.

Here's my code (according to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android)
):

```
// Create an object
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
        .putString("og:type", "books.book")
        .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
        .putString("og:description", "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")
        .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
        .build();

// Create an action
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
        .setActionType("books.reads")
        .putObject("books:book", object)
        .build();

// Create the content
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
        .setPreviewPropertyName("books:book")
        .setAction(action)
        .build();

ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
shareButton.setShareContent(content);
shareButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Result result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SHARING SUCCESS!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "SHARING ERROR! - " + error.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.w(TAG, "SHARING CANCEL!");
    }
});
```

And what I'm getting (with all my attempts):
[image]

> Action Requires At Least One Reference: The action you're trying to
>   publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects.
>   At least one of the following properties must be specified: book.

Please, can you explain, how to correct use OpenGraph in FB SDK 4.0, and correct use `Objects` with `Actions` using SDK 4.0 methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug with the webview version of the dialog that's been fixed. You need to make one small change to your code, I will update our docs as well:

```
// Create an action
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
    .setActionType("books.reads")
    .putObject("book", object)  // <--- don't namespace the object on the action
    .build();

// Create the content
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
    .setPreviewPropertyName("book")  // <--- don't namespace the preview property
    .setAction(action)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as should. Please, also update this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#open_graph).

Comment: But there are now confusion, where are you should use namespaces, and where are not.  
I'm trying implement on practice book quote.  
    `ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
        .setActionType("books.quotes")
        .putString("body", "To be, or not to be...")
        .putObject("book", object)
        .build();`  Should I use just "body", or "quotes:body", or "books:quotes:body"? With this code I'm successfully share the book, but the quote is not attached.

Comment: @Ming Li What are the types used for setPreviewPropertyName(...) beside "book"?

Comment: @Ming Li I want to share a Facebook page, what it's type used with setPreviewPropertyName(...)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You shouldn't use open graph if you're sharing a page.

Comment: @VadymVL did you figure out to use quotes?

Comment: @M.Baraka, I don't remember, it was a quite long time ago :)

Answer (score 0):

In case some someone is looking for it, this is how I fixed my issue.

I also had one issue where when I tried to use another `CallbackManager.Factory.create();`, my `FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>` wasn't being notified, I used only one instance for all Facebook actions.

```
public static void faceBookShareDialog(KoboActivity activity, Content content, Bitmap imageToShare,
            String textToShare) {
        ShareHashtag shareHashtag = new ShareHashtag.Builder().setHashtag(HASH_TAG_KOBO).build();

        SharePhoto photo;
        if (!isFacebookInstalled(activity)) {
            ImageConfig imageConfig = Application.getAppComponent().imageConfigFactory().create(content.getImageId(), ImageType.Cover);
            String imageUrl = imageConfig.getImageRequestURL();

            photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
                    .build();
        } else {
            photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(imageToShare)
                    .build();
        }

        // Create an object
        ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                .putString("og:type", "books.book")
                .putString("og:title", content.getTitle())
                .putString("og:description", content.getDescription())
                .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
                .putPhoto("og:image", photo)
                .build();

        // Create an action
        ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder actionBuilder = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                .setActionType("books.quotes")
                .putString("body", textToShare)
                .putObject("book", object);

        // Create the content
        String contentURL = generateFacebookShareUrl(content.getId(), content.getType(), CreatePhotoQuoteActivity.CAMPAIGN);
        ShareOpenGraphContent contentGraph = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                .setPreviewPropertyName("body")
                .setShareHashtag(shareHashtag)
                .setAction(actionBuilder.build())
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(contentURL))
                .build();

        FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> shareCallback = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.i("FBShare", "fb SHARE canceled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.e("FBShare", "fb SHARE error");
                error.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                String postId = result.getPostId();
                Log.i("FBShare", "fb SHARE success ");
                if (postId != null) {
                    // record successful FB share
                    Log.i(TAG, "post id: " + postId);
                }
            }
        };

        SharePhotoContent photoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .setShareHashtag(shareHashtag)
                .build();

        ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(activity);
        shareDialog.registerCallback(activity.getCallbackManager(), shareCallback);

        shareDialog.show(photoContent);

    }
```